# Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/' did not match any routes in your application

Tags: javascript, html, web, ember.js, routes

I am testing out the Ember.js framework and I am running into a problem when I try to load the page. Currently I have two links on a page and am just trying to figure out how to get one of the routes to be displayed in the {{outlet}}. Whenever I try to load the page I get this error in my console - Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/' did not match any routes in your application

Here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.0/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.5.1/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <div>
            {{#link-to 'index'}} Home {{/link-to}}
            {{#link-to 'history'}} History {{/link-to}}
        </div>

        <div>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        <h1> Index Route Test</h1>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="history">
        <h1> History Route Test</h1>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS file

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS:true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('index');
    this.route('history');
});

App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.Extend({

});
```

Comment: Try removing `this.route('index');` from your `Router` map. Ember will create that for you.

Comment: Thanks. That worked! So Ember always creates this.route('index') automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember automatically routes  `/` to your `'index'` template and corresponding controller without you even having to explicitly name it in your router, so you dont have to include an index route at all.

If you want to keep it in you could use:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('index', { path: '/' });
    this.route('history');
});
```

More information on why Ember already routes `/` to `'index'` [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

Comment: you also don't need to specify index routes, they are freebies.

Comment: True that, my late eyes completely missed it.